# Do I need a controller for each role in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan, roles

My Ruby on Rails 3 application is using Devise and Cancan.

Concerning the roles, I have admins, managers, users and guests. I have some Posts and I use the generated index function to get my Posts list.

How to ensure that admins can index all the posts, managers can index posts in a specific category only and users can index their own posts only?

Cancan is configured and show me an error message when I am trying to do something I am not authorized to.

My question is how about showing, or not showing, records in views, depending the role ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out the documentation:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Checking-Abilities